# Like Box iFrame Generated Code not working

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-likebox

My like box is not showing up with the code generated. I have read through the fixes here and some refer to changing "profile id" to just "id" but there doesn't seam to be any such code in my generated code - also fixed all ampersands (I think)... This is what I have that does not work. How should I change it? Thanks! I get a 404 error with this code:

```
<iframe
src="http//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http://www.facebook
.com/pages/Bluedawg-Design/70870858258;width=450;
height=590;colorscheme=light;show_faces=true;border_color;stream=
true;header=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none;
overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:590px;"
allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 4):

You wiped too much of needed parts, ampersands are important!

And you're missing `:` after `http` which leads to problem.

This is a working version (do not remove parts of next code before trying it as is)

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FBluedawg-Design%2F70870858258&amp;width=450&amp;height=590&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color&amp;stream=true&amp;header=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:590px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

This code works perfectly served by web server but will not work if opened from local machine (not served over HTTP or HTTPS) in later case just put `http:` before `//www.facebook.com`

Comment: LOL, Thank You. Unfortunately still not working: I get: Firefox can't find the file at /plugins/likebox.php?href=http://www.facebook.com/pages/Bluedawg-Design/70870858258&width=450&height=590&colorscheme=light&show_faces=true&border_color&stream=true&header=true.

Comment: This is the page I am linking to: http://www.facebook.com/pages/Bluedawg-Design/70870858258

Comment: Did you removed `http%3A%2F%2Fwww.` part from the start of href?

Comment: I see a lot of &amp in the code you posted... should I remove that?

Comment: No I didn't remove http%3A%2F%2Fwww. Should I

Comment: I used the code exactly as you have it - but I still get: File not found Firefox can't find the file at /plugins/likebox.php?href=http://www.facebook.com/pages/Bluedawg-Design/70870858258&width=450&height=590&colorscheme=light&show_faces=true&border_color&stream=true&header=true.

Comment: @Mary, You probably testing it from local file and not web-server, read notes in updated answer

Answer (score 3):

just change all

```
http://
```

to

```
https://
```

That solved the issue I also wrote a post about it on http://nerudo.mregi.com/social-widgets-twitter-flickr-and-fb-not-showing

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL /social-widgets-twitter-flickr-and-fb-not-showing was not found on this server.
Apache Server at default.jnb2.host-h.net Port 80

Comment: Sorry I'm having issues with my blog ATM

Answer (score 2):

Hi Facebook iframes (like box ) will not work for personal profile or group profile ..please create a one new page by clicking create page link in bottom of facebook using ur facebook account or using new business account ...generate a new code using that link it ll work :) happy coding

Comment: True, this should be considered _before_ the correct spelling or encoding of the url.

Answer (score 1):

Okay this is really stupid, but it just happened to me:

Turn off any browser extension that might be blocking the Like Box! In my case that was "Do not track me" in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same thing happening and it was because I had "DO NOT TRACK ME" installed as well. I disabled it and no more problems.

Answer (score 0):

In the `src=` of the iframe try using `?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook%0A.com%2Fpages%2FBluedawg-Design%2F70870858258` rather than the un-encoded version.

So now the whole thing will look like:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FBluedawg-Design%2F70870858258&amp;width=292&amp;height=590&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color&amp;stream=true&amp;header=true&amp;appId=127211380649475" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:292px; height:590px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: OK I did that, Now it is pulling in my regular web page not the URL we have indicated See: bluedawg.com scroll down I have inserted the facebook Like box in bottom right.

Comment: Unfortunatly, still not working. I get the error: Firefox can't find the file at /plugins/likebox.php?href=http://www.facebook.com/pages/Bluedawg-Design/70870858258&width=292&height=590&colorscheme=light&show_faces=true&border_color&stream=true&header=true&appId=127211380649475.

Comment: At http://bluedawg.com/, I see the like box just fine using Firefox browser on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the iframe code working fine and tested by me on wordpress and magento.

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FEnter_Your_FB_ID_OR_USERNAME&amp;width&amp;height=290&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;show_faces=true&amp;header=true&amp;stream=false&amp;show_border=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:290px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```